# Removing duplicates data from array using angular 9

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array with below list of array as shown in image ,  I would like to remove the duplicates array "Qualif" and "Prod"

[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6wPP.png)

I want to be like that

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iztXC.png)

I have tried with the following conditions

**Scenario1** :

```
   this.Default_data_historique=Object.values(this.nouveau_data_historique.reduce((c,e)=>{
            if (!c[e.PTF_NAME]) c[e.PTF_NAME] =e; return c; },{}));
```

**Scenario2** :

```
this.Default_data_historique= Array.from(new Set(this.nouveau_data_historique))
```

**Scenario3** :

```
this.Default_data_historique=this.nouveau_data_historique.filter(function(elem,index,self){
          return index === self.indexOf(elem)
        });
```

None of the three scenarios above were able to remove the duplicates from that array. Could any one please help on this ?

**Edit:**
sample data i have

```
[
    [{
            "PTF_NAME": "integration",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        },
        {
            "PTF_NAME": "integration",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        }
    ],
    [{
            "PTF_NAME": "Qualif",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        },
        {
            "PTF_NAME": "Qualif",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        }
    ],
    [{
            "PTF_NAME": "Qualif",
            "Salle": "salle2"
        },
        {
            "PTF_NAME": "Qualif",
            "Salle": "salle2"
        }
    ],
    [{
            "PTF_NAME": "Prod",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        },
        {
            "PTF_NAME": "Prod",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        }
    ],
    [{
            "PTF_NAME": "Prod",
            "Salle": "salle2"
        },
        {
            "PTF_NAME": "Prod",
            "Salle": "salle2"
        }
    ]
]
```

what i want

```
[
    [{
            "PTF_NAME": "integration",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        },
        {
            "PTF_NAME": "integration",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        }
    ],
    [{
            "PTF_NAME": "Qualif",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        },
        {
            "PTF_NAME": "Qualif",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        }
    ],

    [{
            "PTF_NAME": "Prod",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        },
        {
            "PTF_NAME": "Prod",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        }
    ]

]
```

Comment: put the actual json in the question.

Comment: @programoholic it's many file json in one data , the data is like the first image just i want to remove or reduce the second array for "Qualif" and "Prod"

Comment: @programoholic i put some arrays in link few arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```js
data = [
    [
        {
            "PTF_NAME": "integration",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        },
        {
            "PTF_NAME": "integration",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        }
    ],
    [
      {
            "PTF_NAME": "Qualif",
            "Salle": "salle1"
      },
      {
            "PTF_NAME": "Qualif",
            "Salle": "salle1"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
            "PTF_NAME": "Qualif",
            "Salle": "salle2"
      },
      {
            "PTF_NAME": "Qualif",
            "Salle": "salle2"
      }
    ],
    [{
            "PTF_NAME": "Prod",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        },
        {
            "PTF_NAME": "Prod",
            "Salle": "salle1"
        }
    ],
    [{
            "PTF_NAME": "Prod",
            "Salle": "salle2"
      },
        {
            "PTF_NAME": "Prod",
            "Salle": "salle2"
        }
    ]
];
function removeDupesInArrayOfObject() {
  const result = [];
  result.push(this.data[0]);
  data.reduce( (first, second, n) => {
      if (first[0].PTF_NAME !== second[0].PTF_NAME) {
          result.push(second);
      }
      return second
  })
  console.log(result);
}
removeDupesInArrayOfObject();
```

Comment: post a few arrays of data in the question

Comment: i don't know why but done , see the link of image few arrays

Comment: ,i try the new answer but nope sorry same result of my first image

Comment: Maybe you don't understand my question , i want the result like the second image , i want to remove the second array of "Qualif" and "Prod" check again what i have and what i want.

Comment: i try the new answer and i have just one array and one item for "integration"

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: what condition do u want to apply in filtering the output?

Comment: post the sample data in the question instead of image

Comment: I'd suggest you create some sample data and post it.

Comment: I create some data See Edit 2

Comment: @anoir.bday check now

Comment: That's nice Thanks , but if you can , i want the first array of "Qualif" and "Prod" , it's mean when Salle : salle1.

Comment: @anoir.bday what do u mean?

Comment: @anoir.bday check the answer now.

Comment: Thank youuuu , really that's helpful for me thank you again

Comment: @anoir.bday I am glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter() method.

```
this.nouveau_data_historique.filter((item,index) => {
  return this.nouveau_data_historique.indexOf(item) === index
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but sorry same thing , same first result